# Fastest bitboard transposition (5x5)

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitboard

For a puzzle-solver I'm writing, I'm looking for the fastest algorithm (minimal number of bit operations) to transpose a 5x5 bitboard with 2 bits per square in the puzzle, so:

```
00 01 02 03 04
05 06 07 08 09
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
```

becomes

```
00 05 10 15 20
01 06 11 16 21
02 07 12 17 22
03 08 13 18 23
04 09 14 19 24
```

The best I've been able to come up with is

```
uint64_t transpose(uint64_t state) {
    return ((state >> 16) &     0x10) |
           ((state >> 12) &    0x208) |
           ((state >>  8) &   0x4104) |
           ((state >>  4) &  0x82082) |
           ((state <<  4) & 0x820820) |
           ((state <<  8) & 0x410400) |
           ((state << 12) & 0x208000) |
           ((state << 16) & 0x100000);
}
```

But it feels like this can be done with significantly less operations. Does anyone know a faster solution? References to good literature on the subject are also very welcome.

Comment: It seems to me like you'd need a no-shift term in there. `transpose(1)` seems to return the wrong result.

Comment: Also, it looks like some of the constants in that `transpose` are based on a 1-bit-per-square bitboard.

Comment: Depending on what you do with it, you could use an additional flag that indicates, whether this should be read as a row major or colum major matrix. Thats something you often find in libraries/programs that work with large matricies: Instead of performing an actal, costly transform operation, they e.g. use a different multiplication algorithm.

Comment: There's probably a good delta-swap sequence for it

Answer (score 1):

A 2048 AI found [here](https://github.com/nneonneo/2048-ai/blob/master/2048.cpp#L33-L48) has a transpose method for a 4x4 grid of 4 bit tiles. Perhaps you can adapt it to your situation. Here is the code:

```
// Transpose rows/columns in a board:
//   0123       048c
//   4567  -->  159d
//   89ab       26ae
//   cdef       37bf
uint64_t transpose(uint64_t x)
{
    uint64_t a1 = x & 0xF0F00F0FF0F00F0FULL;
    uint64_t a2 = x & 0x0000F0F00000F0F0ULL;
    uint64_t a3 = x & 0x0F0F00000F0F0000ULL;
    uint64_t a = a1 | (a2 << 12) | (a3 >> 12);
    uint64_t b1 = a & 0xFF00FF0000FF00FFULL;
    uint64_t b2 = a & 0x00FF00FF00000000ULL;
    uint64_t b3 = a & 0x00000000FF00FF00ULL;
    return b1 | (b2 >> 24) | (b3 << 24);
}
```